# comparing each element in list to 2 elements in another list and make code efficient

Tags: python

I have 2 lists:

```
threshold=[0.123,0.108,0.102,0.087]
retention=[0.19,1,0.57,5,0.09]
```

I want to find out whether each `retention` element is within `threshold` list

my code is here to make it clear:

```
ca2=[(b>retention[0]>a) for b,a in zip(threshold[::1],threshold[1::1])]
ca3=[(b>retention[1]>a) for b,a in zip(threshold[::1],threshold[1::1])]
ca4=[(b>retention[2]>a) for b,a in zip(threshold[::1],threshold[1::1])]
ca5=[(b>retention[3]>a) for b,a in zip(threshold[::1],threshold[1::1])]
ca6=[(b>retention[4]>a) for b,a in zip(threshold[::1],threshold[1::1])]
```

as you can see it requests whether `retention[0]` is between what element in `threshold`

I need to compare each element in `retention`. My code works but it is redundant and I think not efficient. I would like retention also automatically compare with 2 another elements within `threshold`. I would be thankful if you can direct me or help to make the code efficient as retention list might be much longer.

Comment: could you provide an example of your expected output

Comment: How long are your real *threshold* lists?

Comment: How long are your real threshold lists? -10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check that each element of retention is between two elements of threshold, bisect can be used (which is log(n) time for each check.

**Code**

```
from bisect import bisect_left

def binary_search(a, x): 
    """Index of where x would be inserted into a
       return None if x < min(a) or x > max(a)"""
    i = bisect_left(a, x)
    return i if i != len(a) and i > 0 else None

threshold = [0.123,0.108,0.102,0.087]
threshold_asc = threshold[::-1]
retention = [0.123, 0.19,1,0.57,5,0.09, 0.087]

for r in retention:
  print(f'{r} ->> {binary_search(threshold_asc, r)}')
```

**Output**

```
0.123 ->> 3
0.19 ->> None
1 ->> None
0.57 ->> None
5 ->> None
0.09 ->> 1
0.087 ->> None
```

**Complexity**

> O(log(N)) for each check of retention.  This is more efficient than
>   walking the list of thresholds to find pairs of surrounding values which would be O(N).

Comment: I was about to suggest `bisect`, too, but for grouping the elements into bins/categories. Aren't you just checking whether it's between the first and last element? A simple comparison would be enough for this.

Comment: @tobias_k--good point.  Modified my answer to return the index of the insertion point.

Answer (score 1):

You could generate a dictionary with the retention values as keys and threshold comparison lists as values. Also you don't need to create the zip object every iteration if you cast it to a list.

```
t = list(zip(threshold, threshold[1:]))
print({i: [(b > i > a) for b, a in t] for i in retention})
```

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve, but you can use `bisect` to binary-search within the list of thresholds to find the threshold that is just below a given number.

```
retention = [0.19, 1, 0.57, 5, 0.09]
threshold = [0.123, 0.108, 0.102, 0.087]
threshold = [0] + sorted(threshold) # add 0 and sort
bins = {t: [] for t in threshold}
for r in retention:
    k = bisect.bisect(threshold, r) # actually, this is the next threshold
    bins[threshold[k-1]].append(r)  # thus k-1 here to get the lower one
# {0: [], 0.087: [0.09], 0.102: [], 0.108: [], 0.123: [0.19, 1, 0.57, 5]}
```

As in the other `bisect` answer (which yields a very different output), the complexity per query is O(logn), n being the number of thresholds, for a total of O(klogn) for k elements in `retention`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use numpy, you may have a look at `numpy.searchsorted` function, similar to `bisect` others mentioned.

```
np.searchsorted(sorted(thresholds), retentions)
```

would give you indices of where the retention values should be put in sorted thresholds.

Answer (score 0):

I can see two more ways of doing it:

1. If `threshold` is sorted and you want to know if there exists a `j` such that `threshold[j] > retention[i] >= threshold[j+1]` (notice the `>=`) but don't need the value of `j`, then you only need to check `threshold[0] > retention[i] >= threshold[-1]`. This won't work if you need `retention[i]` to be strictly between two consecutive values from `threshold`. This gives you an `O(1)` check per element and, hence, and `O(n)` algorithm.
2. If `retention` is sorted, you can use the two-pointer approach for this. E.g. let's say `retention` is in descending order. Compare `retention[i]` with `threshold[0]` and `threshold[1]`. If `retention[i] < threshold[1]`, you increase `i`, i.e. move to the next value in `retention`. If not, you compare `retention[i]` with `threshold[1]` and `threshold[2]` now. And so on. The check per element is `O(1)` amortized here, hence, this will be an `O(n)` algorithm too unless you need to sort `retention` first.